Insights on Canadian visa delay post-biometrics from the Netherlands
I am an Indian citizen living in the Netherlands. Recently, two months ago, I applied for a Canadian visa from The Hague, and my biometrics were taken. It's been two months since the biometrics were done, and I have seen no updates on my profile. Has anyone had a similar experience so that I can understand the timeline?
I called them up, but they mentioned that they don't know when it will be done, which is true. So, I am looking for someone who has had the same experience.

You could be in for a long wait. Average processing times depend on the visa type and are published here.

For a temporary residence visa applying from the Netherlands, the timescale is currently showing 355 days
Processing times are historical, meaning they’re measured based on how long it took to process 80% of applications in the past


Ah! I underestimated that calculation. I thought, "Why 355 days?"

355 days looks awful.  The same site says 20 days for applications made in India or 596 days for applications made in Poland, so something has gone wrong somewhere in the Canadian bureaucracy.

@Henry In Nigeria it's 700+ days as well
